# Does Stack Overflow release their views data by industry?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, blog

I'm curious on doing some deeper analysis on tags by industry; the closest analogy would be [this piece on trends in government software developers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/07/12/trends-government-software-developers/) where the author matched user views data with the IP address (Maxmind) to get an industry association.

I'm looking at the BigQuery public Stack Overflow data now; and I only see "posts" data and the user data includes names, but no IP addresses.

Are there other ways to duplicate David's analysis for other industries?

Comment: your best bet herefore would probably be the annual developer survey, but that dataset is heavily self selected.

Comment: There will no Ip address next to those user name. Mr RGPD charge max 4% of the company revenues. Not net profit or profit .. revenues.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that you can map IP addresses to employers/industries in any reliable way

Comment: @Pekka웃 That's exactly what the linked blog post has done, however. Reliability is likely suboptimal and very dependent on industry and country (some countries have separate ISPs for government, universities, etc.), but apparently it's reliable enough for a blog on SO.

Comment: @Erik they did it only for government agencies, though, no? Perhaps that can be done with *some* reliability. Outside that, though....

Comment: I don't see any package in Maxmind to map IP address to industry. You can map to the organization name only. Otherwise, you can try IP2Location database and they can map IP address to usage type such as data center, commercial, government, ISP etc.